# What's the proper way to get a local time when TZ=":/etc/localtime"?

Tags: crystal-lang

My environment variable TZ is set to `:/etc/localtime`. File `/etc/localtime` is a symbolic link to file `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago`. So far I am using this to get a local time object:

```
Time.local(
  Crystal::System::Time.load_localtime.not_nil!
) 
# 2019-07-16 20:46:50 -05:00
```

Because the following gives me a Time set to UTC:

```
Time.local   # 2019-07-17 01:46:50 UTC
```

Are the Crystal standard libs suppose to return a UTC location for TZ=":/etc/localtime" or am I suppose to manually set TZ to a timezone (eg "America/Chicago")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Time::Location` only supports values of `TZ` that are paths relative to the zoneinfo data base (for example: `America/Chicago`). It currently can't resolve absolute paths. This could be added as a feature request, though.

`Time.local` gives you a time in `UTC` simply because `Time::Location.load_local` can't understand the value of `ENV["TZ"]` and defaults to UTC. If you simply unset `TZ`, it should work as expected.

When `TZ` is not set, it defaults to the value referenced by `/etc/localtime`. So your custom effort should not be necessary at all. Especially `Crystal::System::Time` is not supposed to be called from user code directly.

Comment: Thanks very much.  `ENV.delete "TZ"` solved it.  Just out of curiosity, how is the TZ variable set on the systems you work on professionally? To a relative path or do you unset it before calling Time related methods?

Comment: Depends... using TZ is usually not very common, you'd rather use `/etc/localtime` instead. Essentially, you only need to set TZ when you want to override the system default. Then you would typically use a relative path to a file in the IANA time zone database, like `America/Chicago`. There are different formats for the TZ variable (including absolute paths) as well, see https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html. But I don't think they're used much, because almost any system has a time zone database available nowadays.